# article vs paper

Tags: word-usage, style

I would like to clarify the stylistic differences in the usage of the words **article** and **paper** (in the meaning **a piece of writing**).

When writing a research article/paper, or its abstract, in which cases it's appropriate to use **the *article* discusses**, and when **the *paper* discusses**?

By the way, does the verb matter? May be **reviews** it's a better choice in some cases? Or **deals with**? Or **examines**?

Comment: [Difference between Paper and Article for scientific writings](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/263206/9880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find your answer here [Difference between Paper and Article for scientific writings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263204/difference-between-paper-and-article-for-scientific-writings)

Concisely, a research article is almost always a piece of writing that is published in a journal whereas a research paper is mostly unpublished. A research paper is normally presented at a conference or is peer-reviewed whereas a research article normally isn't. On the other hand most sources indicate that the difference between a paper and an article is so vague you cannot tell what is actually is.

Concerning your latter question:

Pretty many verbs can follow the words "*article*" and "*paper*". They can: deal with, review, speak about, discuss, mention, examine, describe, say, highlight, face, explain, proclaims, contain, deploy, state, and so on.